# this.setState deletes filter - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate

Okey guys so i have quite an issue here . 
I'm countering this problem since few days so i will be glad if someone can give me a hint how can i fix it . ( or someone can propouse a solution ) .
So i have managed to create my own table via `material-table` library . But in my case i need to have the `docID` and the `docNR` as a value from each checkbox . And that's why i have used a separate component from `material-ui` - `<Checkbox/>` . 
In conclusion i have tracked that my issue is coming from my `handleCheckBox` function . And specifically from my update state function `this.setState` . Is my problem coming from there that my setState function is  [Asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) ? Or am i doing something wrong you will say .

**Visual example**
[image]

**My method**

```
handleCheckboxClick = (clickedItem) => {

        let newDocList = { ...this.state.docList };
        if (clickedItem.checked) {
            newDocList[clickedItem.documentId] = clickedItem.documentNumber;
        } else {
            delete newDocList[clickedItem.documentId];
        }

        let toSee = Object.keys(newDocList).length > 0 ? true : false;

        this.setState({
                docList: newDocList,
                visible: toSee
            }, () => {
                console.log()
            });

        const updatedArray = this.state.items.map((item) => {
            item.checked = item.documentId === clickedItem.documentId ? !item.checked : item.checked;
            return item;
        });

        this.setState({

            items: updatedArray,
        });
    };
```

**P.S.**

I have tried an empty function with only a console init and it is working like a charm .

Comment: can you add your proejct at https://stackblitz.com/fork/react , i would be more than happy to help (had some issues my self with this crap)

Comment: Reproducing code would be useful here because its hard to see whats going on where. It looks like the check action causes your components to update. How/where is the filter ("1987") value stored?

Comment: @RenaldoBalaj Thank you guys that you are stepping in . I have tried to create an example but is giving me some error . Here is the library : https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/filtering and if you you can play around it .  And here is what i have managed to create for example https://react-8az5jb.stackblitz.io

Comment: can't run it :P Error in /turbo_modules/react@16.12.0/cjs/react.development.js (1590:13)
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.  ........

Comment: @RenaldoBalaj try this out https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-tree-7kkyp?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark   . Maybe it cannot be runned thru sandbox . But bassically if u take a look on the library example that i have sended you can add a constructor from above and a simple function to change the `this.setState`

Comment: can you uplaod it in github, a fully working one, with some more info what the problem is and when it works (i tried it in my machine is not sandbox fault)
PLEASE UPLAOD only the table i need not all project

Comment: I will upload it . But as i said you can take a look at https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/filtering . This is my table . It manages the filtering , sorting and searching . I have just added a `<Chekbox/>` from `material-ui` and a simple function to update my state like the examples that i have sended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that upon checking the box your table gets re-rendered which is making it re-create the columns array. This array is used to store the filtering data.

What you'll need to do is store the columns data somewhere outside the render function. For a simple example look at useState (or consider redux/mobx):

```
const BasicFilteringWithState = () => {
  const [columnsData] = useState([
    { title: "Name", field: "name" },
    { title: "Surname", field: "surname" },
    { title: "Birth Year", field: "birthYear", type: "numeric" },
    {
      title: "Birth Place",
      field: "birthCity",
      lookup: { 34: "İstanbul", 63: "Şanlıurfa" }
    }
  ]);

  return (
    <MaterialTable
      title="Basic Filtering Preview"
      columns={columnsData}
      data={[
        { name: "Mehmet", surname: "Baran", birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
        {
          name: "Zerya Betül",
          surname: "Baran",
          birthYear: 2017,
          birthCity: 34
        }
      ]}
      options={{
        filtering: true
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Look at this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-einstein-1ig9m

I left the sample as is and added the one with useState. you can filter both tables and then click the test button at the bottom. You'll see the difference.

In a related note, don't forget to check why your table gets re-rendered because of the checkbox. That might be a sign your components aren't optimized (memoized)...